# Is this correct? "kia semoj ke vi plantas en via ĝardeno?" - is there anything missing?

Tags: translation

I am trying to say

> What seeds are you planting in your garden?

I thought this was correct but, I feel like something is missing...

> Kia semoj ke vi plantas en via ĝardeno?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct is: *"Kiajn semojn vi plantas en via ĝardeno?"*

"kiajn semojn" (= "what kind of seeds") is the object of the verb "plantas" (= "planting"), so it has to have an accusative ending. The word "ke" (= "that") is only used to introduce a subphrase.

Comment: I would say _Kiajn semojn vi plantas en vian ĝardenon?_. Most likely by L1 influence I associate _…en via ĝardeno_ to mean, that you are in the garden and not as a description where you put the seeds into.

Comment: My gut instinct is == @JuhaMetsäkallas … but because you’re putting seeds into the garden’s soil, not just bringing a sack inside the garden walls. In English, “what kind of seeds are you planting _into_ the garden?” is comprehensible and arguably more logical—but it isn’t idiomatic. So for me it’s L1 hyperanalyzation.

p.s. _La Tekstaro_ shows Zamenhof used _planti … en la **teron**_, so this might be more correct, though I’m careful not to deify Zamenhof over modern speakers.

Comment: It depends on what _garden_ means to you in that particular moment, when you say the sentence. If it's a space with plants, table, chairs, a tree, fences ... then you would use "planti en la ĝardeno" but if you see it as just the ground, then you _could_ say "planti en la ĝardenon". Think about "urbo" instead of "garden" and I think it becomes clearer, you would not "planti en urbon" (well, you could, if you were talking figuratively about buildings).

Comment: IMHO _planti en la ĝardeno_ tells, that you are doing the action, planting, in the garden. It doesn't reveal, where you put the seeds into, and thus feels a little awkward.